# $_GET and $_POST is empty on rewriting urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-5.6

I changed my server and in new server all query strings and forms values (with post methods) is empty.

I did rewrite all urls and handle the parameters in my application

this is my .htaccess codes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But in my new server `$_POST` and `$_GET` is empty.

Comment: If there's no `POST` or `GET` data then it's likely you are getting a redirect somewhere

Comment: @LukeTaylor But my codes work on previous server :(

Comment: @MajAfy, Can you share the URL link? I mean anchor tag with HTML code.

Comment: @NarendraVerma site is down for security, what do you need?

Comment: What URL did you use for testing? Put `print_r($_GET);` as first line of your php code and see what it prints.